# How to collapse section using Javascript on single click?

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked multiple times and I have tried different things which are not working.

All I want to do is collapse a section on the click of a button, but I have to click button twice before it actually collapses
(*In CollapseGrid* is getting printed twice and then it goes to *In Collapse*).

How do we make it work in one go without having to click twice?

```js
function collapseGrid(element) {
  console.log("In CollapseGrid");
  element.addEventListener("click", collapse);

};

function collapse() {
  console.log("In Collapse");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="info" onClick="collapseGrid(this)">CLICK</button>
<div class="contnet">
  <p>This should be collapsed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply collapse the next element in the `collapseGrid` function? *e.g.*

```js
function collapseGrid(me) {
  var content = me.nextElementSibling;
  content.style.display = content.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<button class="info" onClick="collapseGrid(this)">CLICK</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>This should be collapsed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this is good but I also have to use this function in other place when I am creating new element:  `var infoTag = document.createElement("button");
  infoTag.classList.add("info");
  infoTag.onclick = collapse;`

Answer (score 1):

Your section gets collapsed on the second click because on the first click you are simply assigning a click listener, but not really executing the collapse function. The code you included inside `collapseGrid()` should be written outside of the function. Then just make the button invoke `collapse()` rather than `collapseGrid()`.

```js
document.querySelector(".info").addEventListener("click", collapse);

function collapse(e) {
  var content = e.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="info" onClick="collapse(this)">CLICK</button>
<div class="contnet" style="display:block">
  <p>This should be collapsed.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to achieve it with a fairly generic function and a some data attributes.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="collapse"]');
elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', collapse));

function collapse() {
  var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
  var element = document.getElementById(target);
  element.style.display = element.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapse1">CLICK 1</button>
  <div class="content" id="collapse1">
    <p>This should be collapsed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapse2">CLICK 2</button>
  <div class="content" id="collapse2">
    <p>This should be collapsed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```